# Disable Intel HD Graphics 4000

Tags: nvidia-geforce, performance-tuning, intel-graphics, minecraft, switchable-graphics

A while back, I called HP, asking how to disable the Intel Graphics and force the computer to use my ATI Radeon. They had me go through the BIOS settings, and I managed to get my laptop to only use my (impressive) Radeon video card.

Now, I have a new laptop with Intel HD Graphics and a (even more impressive) NVIDIA GeForce GT 630M. I notice the same problems I had with my old laptop before I changed the BIOS settings. Minecraft plays slow, benchmark tests use the Intel GPU, and more problems.

The situation is, I forget how to go through the BIOS settings and force the computer to use my NVIDIA card. Can someone please give me steps on how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technology you are using in that laptop is called optimus.

Most laptop vendors will no longer give you the option of forcing the system to use one card or the other.

The first post on this may answer your question:

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72567/can-i-force-steam-to-use-my-nvidia-gpu-instead-of-the-integrated-intel-card

*note in your case you want to add minecraft instead of steam

Answer (score 1):

Thats not true you can force your laptop or pc to use only one by simply going to "My Computer" right clicking and going to properties then device manager locating the HD Graphics right click and click disable. Before you do this make sure your non integrated card is installed properly.

Comment: Also check the setting on your GPU sometimes you need to ajust them for some games to take full advantage of them.